Can you assign an element's class list to a variable by clicking on the element?
The main question I have is: Is there a way to assign to a variable an element's class list by clicking on said element without directly referencing the element in the JavaScript.
Expanding on this, I'm trying to create a function that - on clicking an image in a photo grid - expands the image making it clearer for people to see. I made a for loop that loops through an array that contains the class lists of all images in the grid, the idea was that upon clicking on any one of the images a function that contains the loop would be called and the class list for the image that was clicked would be stored as a variable, the loop would then compare each value in the array to the variable and upon a match would apply a class that enlarges that particular image, this way I could use one function for every image in the grid instead of writing 15+ functions where each one was called depending on the image clicked. I've run into an issue when trying to retrieve the class list for the image that was clicked on - that being I can't figure out how to retrieve the class list for an element by clicking on said element without referencing it. What I mean by this is that I'm not trying to use querySelector() or getElementById()/ClassName() to directly reference the element (in this case photo) as I'd have to write 15+ different functions all corresponding to a specific element (photo). Instead I'm trying to pull the classList for any one element in a group of elements with only one function
As I said I could just make 15+ different functions each with a variable directly assigning that specific images class but that hardly seems like the best way to do this. If this just isn't possible also let me know please.
My JS as it stands:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    
    document.querySelector(".photo-grid").addEventListener("click", e => {
        let figureArray = [] = e.currentTarget.children
        for (let i = 0; i < figureArray.length; i++ ) {
            if (figureArray[i].classList.contains("picture")) {
                console.log(figureArray[i].classList.value);
            }
        }
    });
});

HTML:
<section class="photo-grid">
    <figure class="picture 1 square-image"><img src="tempSource" alt="Covered Gothic Bookcase"></figure>
    <figure class="picture 2 tall-image"><img src="tempSource" alt="Built-in Bookcase & Staircase"></figure>
    <figure class="picture 3 square-image"><img src="tempSource" alt="Extending Coffee Table"></figure>
    <figure class="picture 4 tall-image"><img src="tempSource" alt="Mahogany Fire Guard"></figure>
    <figure class="picture 5 tall-image"><img src="tempSource" alt="Bespoke Ash Staircase"></figure>
    <figure class="picture 6 tall-image"><img src="tempSource" alt="Replica Door"></figure>
    <figure class="picture 7 square-image"><img src="tempSource" alt="Drawer Unit"></figure>
    <figure class="picture 8 tall-image"><img src="tempSource" alt="Casement Windows"></figure>
    <figure class="picture 9 square-image"><img src="tempSource" alt="Staircase"></figure>
    <figure class="picture 10 square-image"><img src="tempSource" alt="Ash Dressing Table"></figure>
    <figure class="picture 11 tall-image"><img src="tempSource" alt="Bespoke Staircase"></figure>
    <figure class="picture 12 tall-image"><img src="tempSource" alt="Country-Style Kitchen"></figure>
    <figure class="picture 13 tall-image"><img src="tempSource" alt="Hand-Cut Dovetails"></figure>
    <figure class="picture 14 square-image"><img src="tempSource" alt="Solid Oak Memorial Bench"></figure>
    <figure class="picture 15 square-image"><img src="tempSource" alt="Bespoke Built-in Cupboards"></figure>
</section>


This question is similar to: How to get all CSS classes of an element?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Did you intend for your edit to loop over each figure and display its classList? I was under the impression you wanted to get the classList of the clicked item.

I do only want the classList of the clicked item, I've evidently made a mistake but I can't see where

See my answer below. e.target is the clicked item.

But I wonder if you are struggling with your nested tags; I'll edit my answer to work with this.

but if I use e.target either nothing is printed to the console or an empty array is printed depending on if the for loop is present or not

See my updated answer below.

You can attach an event listener to each photo, or use event delegation like I have here, attaching the listener to the container element, and checking to see if the clicked item is the desired element. Write a callback function that looks at the event passed to it to determine which element was clicked and log its classList.
Edit: I've modified my example html to match yours. You seem to be struggling with the nested elements: <figure><img></figure>. The clicks are happening on the images, which don't have the "picture" className. I believe you want the className for the figure, even if you clicked on the figure's img child. We're using event delegation here, so using e.currentTarget returns the specific element that we added our event listener to. By looking for the <figure> that is nearest the e.target, we can retrieve the relevant figure tag.


 document.querySelector(".photo-grid").addEventListener(
  "click",
  e => {
    const theFigure = e.target.closest("figure");
    if (theFigure.classList.contains("picture")) {
      console.log(theFigure.classList.value)
    }
  }
 );
<section class="photo-grid">
    <figure class="picture 1 square-image"><img src="tempSource" alt="Covered Gothic Bookcase"></figure>
    <figure class="picture 2 tall-image"><img src="tempSource" alt="Built-in Bookcase & Staircase"></figure>
    <figure class="picture 3 square-image"><img src="tempSource" alt="Extending Coffee Table"></figure>
    <figure class="picture 4 tall-image"><img src="tempSource" alt="Mahogany Fire Guard"></figure>
    <figure class="picture 5 tall-image"><img src="tempSource" alt="Bespoke Ash Staircase"></figure>
    <figure class="picture 6 tall-image"><img src="tempSource" alt="Replica Door"></figure>
    <figure class="picture 7 square-image"><img src="tempSource" alt="Drawer Unit"></figure>
    <figure class="picture 8 tall-image"><img src="tempSource" alt="Casement Windows"></figure>
    <figure class="picture 9 square-image"><img src="tempSource" alt="Staircase"></figure>
    <figure class="picture 10 square-image"><img src="tempSource" alt="Ash Dressing Table"></figure>
    <figure class="picture 11 tall-image"><img src="tempSource" alt="Bespoke Staircase"></figure>
    <figure class="picture 12 tall-image"><img src="tempSource" alt="Country-Style Kitchen"></figure>
    <figure class="picture 13 tall-image"><img src="tempSource" alt="Hand-Cut Dovetails"></figure>
    <figure class="picture 14 square-image"><img src="tempSource" alt="Solid Oak Memorial Bench"></figure>
    <figure class="picture 15 square-image"><img src="tempSource" alt="Bespoke Built-in Cupboards"></figure>
</section>




This is exactly what I was looking for, Thank you very much mykaf!

This is indeed exactly what I was looking for however, once again, while it works in the code snippet it does not work in practice. Upon clicking each photo nothing is logged to the console, I tried changing it to e.target.children.classList.contains but it keeps throwing an error. Though at least something is logged when this happens which makes me think that the issue is that the event isn't delegating, is there a fix for this?

@ScalarQuantity: "while it works in the code snippet it does not work in practice" - What's the difference in this case?  Please update the question to include a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem you are struggling to describe.

Your modification wouldn't work because the children property returns an HTMLCollection, rather than a single element. An HTMLCollection does not have a classList; you would need to iterate over the HTMLCollection to retrieve the classList of each individual element.

I have updated the code in the question as requested. I have iterated over the HTML collection and it is now working (before anyone says anything, yes I have to use currentTarget instead of target or it doesn't work), however, I am receiving the classList of all the figure elements rather than the classList from just the clicked one

Yes! Your updated answer works perfectly! Thanks very much mykaf, for your time, effort and explanation. It seems obvious now you said it but somehow it didn't click with me that the img element was being clicked and not the figure element.

I'm glad to help. This confusion regarding the target and currentTarget points to the importance of providing the actual html required to recreate the problem. I'd appreciate it you would mark my answer as your accepted answer.

The documentation appears to offer some options.  You could get the whole list of classes as a string:


document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  const classes = e.target.classList.value;
  console.log(classes);
});
<button class="foo baz">click</button>



Or perhaps you want to iterate over the list individually:


document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  const classes = [];

  for (const value of e.target.classList.entries()) {
    classes.push(value[1]);
  }
  
  console.log(classes);
});
<button class="foo baz">click</button>



In these examples I'm simply referencing the clicked element from the target of the click event itself.  Presumably you have the same option available to you, the code shown just doesn't demonstrate that.  If this function is being invoked by a click event then you should probably at least pass along the event object to this function.  Or if you have some other way to identify the element, that works too.

In my HTML I have an onclick="enlarge()" to call the function instead of an event listener. How would I use the .target property if I don't have the e from the event listener used in the above example?

@ScalarQuantity: That's a different question, but this question appears to provide some options for that.  My recommendation is to start moving away from inline event calls like that and to attach events from code (e.g. addEventListener) instead.

Ok I'll look into that, thanks for the help
